# What are the commands to solve the following

Tags: linux, text-processing, pipe

OBJECTIVE

I have a file called graph that contains the textual description of a graph by listing all existing links between nodes.
Each line contains one link, expressed like this :

```
number1->number2
```

Where `number2` is the number of the node that receives a link from the node whose number is `number1` (there is a link from `number1` to `number2`).

I need to find the most "popular" node which is actually the node that receives the most links.

CONSTRAINTS

1. I need to use only one command (with several pipes) not the `sed` or `awk` commands.
2. The command line should display only two numbers: the number of the most popular node, and the number of links received by this node (not necessarily in that order).

WHAT'S INSIDE THE GRAPH FILE

```
110->41
74->125
117->29
135->85
24->68
34->25
58->81
18->77
108->20
36->89
45->43
75->28
57->18
135->5
74->126
18->7
40->63
18->123
9->17
133->2
86->10
91->12
125->74
133->25
121->53
135->41
55->81
60->25
16->78
47->40
112->30
12->99
71->107
135->42
31->53
108->99
54->55
49->69
37->24
26->31
64->93
47->65
98->14
108->34
15->60
80->119
40->65
41->110
42->13
95->56
134->62
18->29
40->47
43->125
103->102
18->93
79->68
21->35
87->116
108->124
40->29
94->75
48->33
59->20
18->119
18->63
51->17
45->133
18->22
6->72
43->15
108->127
73->115
12->98
77->88
43->102
29->67
12->106
65->30
46->94
126->13
77->135
126->129
52->10
43->129
89->67
118->91
109->57
80->134
18->38
7->123
25->121
114->21
13->125
62->50
46->28
43->70
99->108
24->130
14->9
126->85
8->116
89->36
128->34
28->109
126->5
95->86
20->83
95->76
86->111
89->112
103->78
132->39
53->121
41->54
101->122
18->33
18->116
133->120
129->85
12->71
19->46
12->118
59->25
79->6
81->58
119->127
31->26
15->59
92->7
33->44
123->124
40->112
86->74
30->47
79->111
27->23
18->71
75->94
38->29
77->75
120->104
99->127
23->22
75->32
11->115
52->111
79->130
40->89
4->114
89->4
123->7
17->97
85->53
18->11
55->54
93->96
43->126
126->42
113->8
40->8
35->21
130->127
9->98
83->131
3->64
105->103
18->68
23->122
0->77
124->25
52->67
77->25
48->1
17->103
48->10
111->79
56->52
104->105
69->129
18->27
29->115
8->114
108->25
61->106
48->6
68->118
118->68
130->124
135->125
18->14
67->92
4->80
17->100
10->132
106->61
39->19
8->113
40->38
88->66
15->39
46->32
9->43
37->111
1->35
128->109
91->128
40->117
18->64
20->77
82->25
86->87
18->6
37->79
66->31
86->33
43->125
16->2
107->88
47->117
47->88
20->135
73->84
32->49
72->54
89->84
52->56
29->132
117->52
50->78
43->108
61->19
18->0
9->0
86->7
39->64
44->86
12->43
11->116
1->21
90->51
40->3
18->95
78->131
100->16
127->130
133->100
126->41
76->95
114->25
63->27
118->51
34->128
76->50
27->25
131->82
116->66
43->45
35->15
17->4
36->40
122->3
78->82
102->105
18->107
17->120
5->129
114->15
2->48
133->16
84->73
18->115
18->37
81->24
18->130
123->113
97->5
37->72
91->90
20->24
115->38
96->25
1->15
70->101
89->97
79->37
22->101
40->100
3->25
40->36
```

Comment: Generally it's better to speak to a tutor / teacher if you are stuck on a homework question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I'm sorry am I not allowed to ask questions like that on this website? (serious question)

Comment: You are but... 1) it's often polite on any site to state that you are stuck with your homework 2) it's **much** better to state why you are stuck (what part of it can you do, what can't you do).  3) Assignments are often based on work taught in class. A lot of teachers will easily spot when someone (not in your class) gave you the answer.

Comment: What's the expected output for your sample input?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick only two numbers, the number of the most popular node and the number of links received by this node

Comment: @William the most popular node being the one that is repeated? I can't see a repetition of a "node" in your sample.

Comment: What is the expected output if there is a tie for the most popular node?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity This is only a sample of what's inside the file, the actual file contains over a 1000 lines and several nodes are repeated. should i put a longer sample of what's inside the file?

Comment: @ShaneBishop sorry I just removed the tag, thank you

Comment: @ShaneBishop no idea in case there's a tie, i'm trying to figure out wich command does that in the first place

Comment: Often an assignment will give sample input and the correct sample output so you can check your work. Do you have both?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick well that's the thing, all other questions have a sample but this one doesn't, but in short the outpout should be something like `108->48` i.e the line that has the most popular node followed by the number of links received

Comment: hello william, and welcome to unix.se . Your last comment doesn't fit with the question itself : you say that the result "108->48" would mean that 108 was the most popular node and had 48 links? whereas in your question "108->48" means a link from node 108 to node 48 ... This seems strange

Comment: hint for your question : if you need to find the "most popular node on a receiving end of a link in the graph file" :  you need to figure out how to assemble simple unix commandes ( cut, tr , sort , uniq ) to only display the last elements and count them and show the most often cited one. This is rather basic unix stuff (the most "difficult" here, as you can't use sed nor awk, is to figure out how to only show the right-hand-side elements only, and then count them). You can answer by combining 4 commands (with some parameters from some of them), ie with 3 pipe only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```bsh
cut -d '>' -f 2 graph | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

This will print the number of links to the node and the node on the same line (the number of links comes first, and the node is second). If you want them to appear on separate lines, use the following:

```bsh
cut -d '>' -f 2 graph | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1 | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Or you could have nice human-readable output like this:

```bsh
cut -d '>' -f 2 graph | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1 | xargs printf 'Number of links: %s\nNode: %s\n'
```

First, we `cut` the output with `>` as the delimiter and get the second field (`-f 2`), which is the node the edge leads to.

Next we use `sort`. We sort because otherwise `uniq` will not work as desired (`uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent).

Next we use `uniq -c` to get the counts for each node.

We sort again with the numerical order with the `-n` option. After this second `sort`, the output is in order from the node with the least number of incoming links to the node with the most incoming links.

`tail -n 1` returns the last line, i.e., the line for the node with the most incoming links.

The `tr` part in the second version replaces the space character between the count and the node with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man cut sort uniq tail` and do something like

```
cut '-d>' -f 2 graph | \
  sort -n | \
  uniq -c | \
  sort -n | \
  tail -n 1
```